# How to pass the credential to Translation API v3?

Tags: java, google-authentication, google-translation-api

I am using Google Cloud Translate v3 API Java Client. The Java Client code samples work great. The authentication of the code samples is done using the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable.

I need to develop code that will run in an application server that I have no control over the environment variables. So I need to use another way to get the call authenticated. 
[Setting Up Authentication for Server to Server Production Applications](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production), under "Passing the path to the service account key in code" has a code sample (choose the JAVA tab) that works for the Storage service, but I can't find a similar way to pass the GoogleCredentials to Translation v3 API Java Client. Does anyone know?

Also, I can't find the Java doc for v3 API. https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-clients/latest/index.html shows version "0.119.0-alpha" and it does not list the package com.google.cloud.translate.v3. Is there a separate java doc page ?

Answer (score 5):

I think I found a solution.
The client API javadoc doesn't list com.google.cloud.translate.v3 but it does list com.google.cloud.translate.v3beta1. In the javadoc for TranslationServiceClient, i.e. https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-clients/latest/com/google/cloud/translate/v3beta1/TranslationServiceClient.html
there's a mention of setting credential, and this method worked!

```
 TranslationServiceSettings translationServiceSettings =
     TranslationServiceSettings.newBuilder()
         .setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(myCredentials))
         .build();
 TranslationServiceClient translationServiceClient =
     TranslationServiceClient.create(translationServiceSettings);
```

Comment: How to  build `myCredentials`